# unable to download doebioresearch package due to stats import

Tags: r, statistics

I had recently got my package "doebioresearch" published in CRAN. It had import of stats (>=4.02) package which is part of system library.

Q1) Now some of the users are not able to download my package. One of the users shared this Error

```
> install.packages("doebioresearch")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/RUMIT PATEL/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘stats’ is not available
installing the source package ‘doebioresearch’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/doebioresearch_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 15795 bytes (15 KB)
downloaded 15 KB

* installing *source* package 'doebioresearch' ...
** package 'doebioresearch' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'stats' 3.6.1 is already loaded, but >= 4.0.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'doebioresearch'
* removing 'C:/Users/RUMIT PATEL/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/doebioresearch'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘doebioresearch’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\RUMIT PATEL\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqu6Cgi\downloaded_packages’
```

Q2 stats belong to system library, so it is possible that some of the users might not have stats package?
Please suggest me a solution or path. This is my first package.

Comment: I suppose you developed your package on R 4.0 and, although you didn't explicitly state in the description that you need R version >= 4.0, you stated `stats >= 4.0.2` in the dependencies. Users with R 3.6, like the person that send you that error message, can't install it, because `stats` is a base package and in order to update it they need to update their R version.

Comment: Usually you don't need to specify required versions of packages, and you should only do so if you know that your package doesn't work in older, but relatively recent, previous versions.  In those cases you can sometimes use the `backports` package to supply workaround versions of functions.

Answer (score 2):

stats version 4.0.2 is a very new version of the package, if users don't have the newest Rversion they have the older stats package. Since stats is distributed with the base installation the binary packages for older R versions are not available, so their R tries to install it from source and therefore needs rtools installed.

If you really need the stats >= 4.0.2 dependency I'd recommend also depending on R version >= 4.0.2 but this would make the install on older versions completely impossible.

But I guess that you don't really need the stats >= 4.0.2 dependency, stats has a very stable interface and your package probably also works with a lower version, so people installing your package won't need to compile the newer version of stats.

Comment: So I should have used lower version of stats eg (>=3.6.1) as I am just using lm(), anova() and shapiro.test() of stats package. Thanks for the response and suggestion

Comment: seeing that `stats` is a base package, probably you don't need to specify a version.. Rather you should specify what R version to use. `lm` `anova` `shapiro.test` have been around for a while if not ever.. so unless something specific has been changed with the newest release that you absolutely need, you may not need to ask for a specific version and you should be fine with R >= 3.0